# Selecting values of select dropdown using javascript code

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form.php which adds username selected from dropdown select, and user payments received into database. After inserting values by going to add_form.php, it comes back to form.php. I have sent the username from add_form.php to form.php by using below code

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result==1){
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Payment added successfully");';
echo 'window.open("form.php?name='.$name.'", "_self");';
echo '</script>';
}
```

Now problem is that, how can I use this get parameter to select the passed value into dropdown automatically? I want the end user of the application to select a name once and add multiple payments, i.e., selected name should be there even after payment is added into db

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want but if filling up the select with options dynamically (with some js variables) is what you want then you can try something like.

```
$("#id_something").empty();
$("#id_something").append('<option selected="selected" value='+somejsvariable+'>'+someotherjsvariable+'</option>');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually I want the select, updated with the parameter received via GET in form.php